# Creating recursive methods given BinaryTree

Tags: java

I'm studying for a test in a few hours, and I'm going over some practice problems but I'm really having trouble with recursion related problems. I was wondering if someone could walk me through how to do these?

Using the `BinaryTree class` below, create the following `recursive` methods:

- `sum()` – returns the sum of all values in the BinaryTree.
- `countGreaterThan(int)` – returns the number of nodes that have values greater than the specified integer.
- `isValidSearchTree()` – returns true if the Binary Tree is a valid search tree and false otherwise.

I get the basic premise of how to create these functions like for example, for the sum function it'd usually go something like:

```
int sum = 0
for(int i; i<binaryTree.size(); i++){
    sum += binaryTree[i]
}
```

Or something similar. But I don't really know how to apply these concepts to a `BinaryTree` with `nodes` and make them `recursive` as well? The code I'm provided with is given below.

```
public class BinaryTree {
 private int data;
 private BinaryTree leftChild;
 private BinaryTree rightChild;

 public BinaryTree(int val) {
     data = val;
     leftChild = null;
     rightChild = null;
  }

  // Get methods
 public int getData() { return data; }
 public BinaryTree getLeftChild() { return leftChild; }
 public BinaryTree getRightChild() { return rightChild; }

 // Set methods
 public void setData(int val) { data = val; }
 public void setLeftChild(BinaryTree left) { leftChild = left; }
 public void setRightChild(BinaryTree right) { rightChild = right; }
}
```

Comment: for the method `isValidSearchTree()`, what defines a valid search tree?

Comment: so you got what want or you need more clarification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think you have too many questions, but with [this meta discussion in mind](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), I'll walk through the recursive sum function and explain how to tackle a problem like these recursively.

These algorithms all appear to require [depth first search](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_C-kq71sYk) so I recommend you also check out the linked video.

The neat thing about recursion is allows us to think only about what each particular node has to do. For the sum example, that means returning the value it has stored, plus the recursive sum of its children.

```
public int exampleSum(){
   // Start with the data we have.
   int sum = this.getData();

   // Then get the data we need (from each child, which can be done recursively).
   if (this.getLeftChild() != null) {
       sum += this.getLeftChild().exampleSum();
   }
   // Do the same for the right node.

   return sum; 
}
```

What this equates to is going through each node, and getting the sum of each subtree.

Imagine its a group of people standing in the shape of a binary tree, where everyone has a 'parent' and 0 to 2 'children', and they all hold a number.

Instead of someone going through and asking each person what their number is and adding them all up (looping), we start at the top, the first person asks their children for their sum, and their children ask their children, etc (recursion).

Each person adds the number their children gave them to their number, then hands it to their parent.

The two special cases are when the person has no children, so they stop and just hand their number to their parent, and the 'root' node who gives their number to whatever function asked them in the first place.

I recommend drawing a binary search tree and going through this algorithm yourself.

I hope this was helpful, and if it was could you like this answer.

In future I recommend asking one question at a time. Good luck with your test!

Answer (score 1):

You should study the **power** of `recursion`, but I have coded the methods that you asked for, all these are working like a charm:

```
/*
* INPUT:   Root node
* OUTPUT:  Sum of the data of all nodes of tree
*/

public void sum(TreeNode node)
{
    if(node == null)
        return;

    sum(node.leftNode);  // recursive call to left subtree of each node
    sum += node.data;
    sum(node.rightNode);  // recursive call to right subtree of each node
}


/*
* INPUT:   Root node , threshold value
* OUTPUT:  sum of all node's data, that rae greater than "value"
*/

public void countGreaterThan(TreeNode node, int value)
{
    if(node == null)
        return;

    countGreaterThan(node.leftNode,value);
    if( node.data > value)    // only adds is node.data is greater than given value 
        sum += node.data;
    countGreaterThan(node.rightNode,value);
}   

/*
* INPUT:  nothing
* OUTPUT:  call to its helper function, taking MIN, MAX, and root as input
*/

public boolean isBST()  
{ 
    return isBSThelper(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE,  Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
}   

public boolean isBSThelper(TreeNode node, int min, int max) 
{ 
    if (node == null)   //empty tree is always a BST 
        return true; 

    if (node.data < min || node.data > max) //if node breaks the min/max condition 
        return false; 

    // recursive call to left subtree and right subtree
    return (isBSThelper(node.leftNode, min, node.data-1) && isBSThelper(node.rightNode, node.data+1, max)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide a recursive attempt that you made of `sum()`, I will be able to help you much easier. I'll update this answer with something more comprehensive once you provide an example.

As a general hint/tip, when dealing with recursion and binary trees:

1. Draw it out and trace a possible solution. This can help you visualize what you need to code.
2. For any given node, you want to visit all of its children. This means if it only has one child (left or right) you visit that child, if it has two (left and right) you visit both, and if you do not have any children, you terminate (that's a pretty big base case hint right there).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! the other guy was close but his method didn't work, it did put me on the right path however.

```
      int sumNodes(BinaryNode<Integer> root)
      {
          int sum = 0;
          if(root == null){
              return 0;
          }

          if (root.getLeft() != null) {
              sum += sumNodes(root.getLeft());
          }

          if (root.getRight() != null) {
               sum += sumNodes(root.getRight());
          }
          sum+= root.getValue();
          return sum;

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to check for existence of left/right node. Just made the call base case is enough to handle the null case